# How to make a reaction collector for a bot's message

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Now I'm making a reaction collector, and it worked, but the bot would add a reaction to my message instead of it's own, but when I made it add the reaction to itself, I can't use the variable I used in the promise for the collector.

```
import { ICommand } from 'wokcommands'
import { Message, MessageEmbed, MessageReaction, User } from 'discord.js'

export default {
    category: 'Testing',
    description: 'Tests the collector system',
    hidden: true,

    callback: ({ message, channel }) => {
    

        const answerUsernameEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Please confirm this action')
        .setColor('#1be730')
        message.reply({
            embeds: [answerUsernameEmbed]
        }).then((newMessage) => {
            newMessage.react('')
        })

        const filter = (r: MessageReaction, user: User) => {
            return user.id === message.author.id
        }

        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({
            filter,
            max: 1,
            time: 1000 * 10,
        })

        collector.on('collect', reaction => {
            console.log(reaction.emoji.name)
        })
        
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            if (collected.size === 0) {
                const badCollector = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('You did not react in time...')
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                message.reply({
                    embeds: [badCollector]
                })
                return
            }

            let text = 'Collected:\n\n'

            collected.forEach((message) => {
                text += `${message.emoji.name}\n`
            })

            message.reply(text)
        })
    }
} as ICommand
```

As you can see, I could use .then to make the bot react to its own message, but then newMessage is inaccessible outside of the scope of the promise, and I can't put the collector inside the promise, because that gives me like 8 errors at once...

Answer (score 0):

When trying to react to messages, it's best to use the await function and set the message to a variable. As in:

```
const reactMsg = await message.reply({embeds: 
    [answerUsernameEmbed]}).then(reactMsg.react(''))
```

This should avoid your message variable being inside or outside of the global scope. Now you can use it anywhere, and you still get the reaction on the correct message as it's literally waiting for it to send, then reacting to it.

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages.
The DJS guide has some helpful information on this if you need more help and haven't checked it out yet.